# How to find the other part of a string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make C# program that gets a line on a website and use it.
Unfortunately, I don't know the full line on the site. I only know "`steam://joinlobby/730/`". Although, what comes after "`/730/`" is always different.

So i need help getting the full line that comes after it.

What I've got:

```
public void Main()
{
    WebClient web = new WebClient();

    // here is the site that i want to download and read text from it.
    string result = web.DownloadString("http://steamcommunity.com/id/peppahtank"); 

    if (result.Contains("steam://joinlobby/730/"))
    {
        //get the part after /730/
    }
}
```

I can tell you that it always ends with "`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`"
so: `steam://joinlobby/730/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx`.

Comment: you mean something like this?    string strippedResult = result.Replace("steam://joinlobby/730/", ""); this will return the steam://joinlobby/730/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx  without the steam://joinlobby/730/

Comment: [Regex.match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) could possibly help

Comment: That's a `URI`.  There's a `Uri` class that could do this for you

Comment: *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."* [Jamie Zawinski](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's to prevent you from just splitting the string on '/730/'?

```
result.Split(@"/730/")[1]
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method for this particular case would be to take the first part, and then just skip that many characters

```
const string Prefix = @"steam://joinlobby/730/";

//...

if(result.StartsWith(Prefix))
{
    var otherPart = result.SubString(Prefix.Length);
    // TODO: Process other part
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for responding.

Although,
I now am trying:

    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    string result = web.DownloadString("http://steamcommunity.com/id/peppahtank");
    const string Prefix = @"steam://joinlobby/730/";
    if (result.StartsWith(Prefix))
    {
        var otherPart = result.Substring(Prefix.Length);
        MessageBox.Show(otherPart); //to see if i actually get the correct response 
    }
And it seems like i just dont get a messagebox popped open.
I'm probably doing something idiotic...

Comment: There could be other problems - best to isolate them and open another question. Also, without formatting, that code is gobbleygook - use a code pasting tool if you _must_ include code in comments

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your result is not null and begins with `steam://joinlobby/730/`

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpaces(result) && result.StartsWith("steam://joinlobby/730/"))
{
     string rest = result.SubString(("steam://joinlobby/730/").Length);
}
```